# VSCode stuck on formatting c++ in remote server

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am trying to use VSCode on a windows machine, and connected to a linux server via ssh. The c++ formatter won't work for the remote no matter what I do. I tried:

- Updating VSCode to latest stable version
- Uninstalling and reinstalling C++ extension
- Deleting the .vscode and .vscode-server folder on server (under my home directory)

But the extension **worked** when I tried to connect to the server using my MacBook.

In the output panel, there's no options for C++ plugin, and I don't know how to check the output of the formatter.